# .htaccess & mod_rewrite redirect issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Alright. I'm having no luck. So I figured I'd see if you all could help make some sense of this issue.

I've inherited a site that previously had a lot of different subdomains, which have now all been written into the .htaccess file to rewrite as subdirectories (i.e., *blog.site.com* becomes *site.com/blog*).

To avoid duplicate content issues, I also need to rewrite all *site.com* URL's as ***www***.site.com. And even though the current rules look good to me, they're apparently not rewriting all the subdirectories of the domain. (I've never been that great with RegEx, so that could be part of the problem.)

Here are the current rules from .htaccess:

```
#---------------------------------
# Start rewrite engine
#---------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} !^$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\..+$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^docs\..+$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>

#---------------------------------
# Rewrite some of our subdomains
#---------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.site\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*)$ "http://www.site.com/blog/$1" [R=301,QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^docs\.site\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.site.com/docs/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wiki\.site\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.site.com/wiki/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>


#---------------------------------
# Wordpress specific - do not place anything below this line
#---------------------------------

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

(Obviously, some of them exist to allow for a local dev environment, etc).

Any thoughts on why I'm not seeing *site.com/directory* rewritten as ***www***.site.com/directory? What am I missing here?

Comment: The rules look good to me too (except for the missing `RewriteEngine On` at the top. What kind of results are you getting?

Comment: Should've added the 'RewriteEngine On'. This was pasted from a larger .htaccess file, so it exists - just not in the snippet.

When I test this, I'm seeing things not rewritten. So:

site.com/test/

does *not* currently rewrite as 

www.site.com/test

Comment: But if there are other rules, please post those too as they may be interfering.

Comment: Good point. Edited it with the remainder of the rules. See above.